# Kaltura player Android Chrome Browser not Casting

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast, kaltura

I managed to configure a Chromecast custom receiver app for Kaltura. It works well on Mac and PC but refuses to call the manifest on Android.

I have gone through the debugger and no apparent errors are reported. The receiver app is called but nothing else happens.

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you,

David Eusse

Comment: After putting the Chromecast device into debug mode, I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'CastReceiverContext' of undefined
    at <anonymous>
This is on https://www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js

Comment: Hi David and thanks for that -we did fix a bug related to this issue in our latest version -- https://github.com/kaltura/playkit-js-cast-sender/releases/tag/v0.3.3 - make sure you are using the last one and try again :-)

Comment: Hello Itay,
I am using player V2.80 right now since I can't upgrade to V3 yet. I can't find which files need to be replaced.
Any help will be really appreciated,

Comment: checking and will update shortly

Comment: hi @DavidEusse 2.82 should include a fix to android cast issue. I do not yet know the release data but if you are deploying your own you can pull the 2.82 branch and test it

Comment: Ok, I replaced the mw.EmbedPlayerChromecast.js file and it works ! PC, Mac and different versions of Android.

Thank you very much,

Comment: by the way - we update the version with a fix - so you can take the latest one now :-)

Answer (score 0):

upgrade to the latest version- we fixed the issue - thanks!